# Authenticating users on a Qt Server

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to implement an authentication system using C++/QtTcpSocket for a personal project (A Multiplayer Chess Game).

My friend suggested a method for verifying a user but I wanted to ask if there was an easier or better way. Coming from a Python background and mostly doing this project to develop a deeper understanding of C++.

I will post the method my friend suggested and ask for maybe a better solution.

He built it in a kind of pseudo code fashion. The server is mostly built, I am now hoping to implement Authentication

*cheers

```
void process_packet(PACKET *pkt)
{
    switch(pkt->PacketID)
    {
        case 0: // let's say packet id 0 is the logon packet; packet contents are username and password
        {
            //let's say packet size is 101 bytes; packet id was already received, so get the other 100 bytes
            unsigned char BUFFER[101] = {0}; // i always add an extra byte to the end of the buffer to allow for off-by-one errors ^_^

            int result = recv_packet(pkt->cSocket, 100, BUFFER);

            if(result <= 0)
                return; // connection error; no packet data was received

            unsigned char *UserName = BUFFER+0; //+0 is not neccessary, but the username starts at the beginning. just getting the point across.
            unsigned char *PassWord = BUFFER+50;

            //side note: if we did "unsigned long *blah = BUFFER+4" or something, we would have to make sure the byte order is right. network byte order is BIG ENDIAN
            //  WINDOWS byte order is LITTLE ENDIAN

            result = QueryDatabase("SELECT username, password FROM chess_players WHERE username = '%s'", FILTER_INVALID_CHARS(UserName));

            // check result

            unsigned char ServerResponse[2] = {0};

            if(result['password'] == PassWord)
            {
                ServerResponse[0] = 1; // packet id will be 1. the next byte can be 1 or 0 to indicate logon success or failure.
                ServerResponse[1] = true; // so packet 0x0101 mean logon success, packet 0x0100 means logon failure
                send_packet(pkt->cSocket, ServerResponse, 2);
            } else {

                ServerResponse[0] = 1;
                ServerResponse[1] = false;
                send_packet(pkt->cSocket, ServerResponse, 2);
            }
        }
        break;

        default:
        {
            // received an unknown packet id; send a packet to the client that indicates an error_status_t

            unsigned char *ServerResponse[2] = {0};
            ServerResponse[0] = 2; // packet id 2 means server error
            ServerResponse[1] = 0; // error code 0 means 'unknown packet id'

            send_packet(pkt_cSocket, ServerResponse, 2);
        }
        break;
    }

    delete pkt; // must delete pkt, was created with 'new' in get_client_packets()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have followed the fortune client/server examples, you should have a QTcpServer (`Rfserver`) with a QThread subclass (`Rfdevice`, its instance variable is called `thread` in the following code) that contains a QTcpSocket (`listenSocket`).

Having said that, in your server class, listen for incoming connections, my setup looks like this:

```
void Rfserver::incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor){
    if(thread){ //if thread exists, there is probably still an open connection
        if(thread->listenSocket){//if thread exists and the listenSocket is filled, there is definately an open connection
            if(thread->listenSocket->state() == QAbstractSocket::UnconnectedState){ 
                //but alas, it could just be in the unconnected state, if so kill it.
                this->disconnect();
                thread->terminate();
                thread=0;
                connected=false;
            }//otherwise, do nothing, because the software is happily connected to a device
        }
    }
    if(!thread){    //if no thread exists, we are by no means connected
        thread = new rfdevice(socketDescriptor, this); //set up a new thread
        //this first connection communicates the string from your socket to the server parent...use it if you want.
        connect( thread, SIGNAL(RemoteButton(QString)),this,SLOT(remoteButton(QString)),Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection); 
        connect( thread, SIGNAL(error(QTcpSocket::SocketError)),this,SLOT(tcpError(QTcpSocket::SocketError)),Qt::AutoConnection);
        connect( thread, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(threadZero())); //I have a threadZero function that deletes all the data then schedules the socket for deletion.
        thread->start(); 
        connected=true;
        QString *welcome = new QString("Enter your password:\r\n");
        echoCommand(welcome); //this is a function you will implement that sends the welcome message to the pending device.
    }
}
```

Okay, so now, when a device tries to connect to the server the device is presented with `"Enter your password:\r\n"`.  Your device will respond to this with a password and username perhaps. But the Qt side of things would look like this:

```
/*
 FUNCTION:read
    this is a polling runloop that listens for data as long as the socket is connected or connecting.  If a
 write is ever scheduled, it will be called from this runloop..
 */
void Rfdevice::read(void){
    while((listenSocket->state() == QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState) || (listenSocket->state() == QAbstractSocket::ConnectingState)){
        //if there is data available to send write it to the socket
        if(dataToSend) this->write();
        if(listenSocket->waitForReadyRead(50)) readBytes(); 
        //wait for 50ms for data from the device
        //if there is ever data available to be read, read it.
    }
}
```

Your device responds with a username/password in the format `username---password\r\n`.  Then the socket does this:

```
/*
FUNCTION:readBytes
this is like a callback function because it only gets called when there is data available for read.
It basically converts the data to a string.
 */
void Rfdevice::readBytes(void){
    QByteArray newData;
    newData = listenSocket->readAll();
    QString *recieved = new QString(newData);
    QStringList userAndPass = recieved.split("---");//this is your delimiter
    QString username = userAndPass.at(0);
    QString password = userAndPass.at(1);

    //NOW, check the username and password vs your SQL or wherever it's saved.

}
```

The pseudo-code is pretty complete on the particulars.  Hopefully you can put it all together!  Let me know if you need more code.

Answer (score 1):

This seems rather C-stylish and not like the Qt way of doing things.
There is no general answer to your question but my suggestions are the following:

Listen to the `newConnection()` signal of the `QTcpServer`. Your handler has to call the `nextPendingConnection()` to get the next client waiting in the queue. The first thing you will do is probably your user authentication. 
Once authenticated, you keep the QTcpSocket in your list of active connections.

Take a look at e.g. the fortune client/server examples how to actually write/read packets. 
You might also want to look into the stream operators `<<` to serialize your objects. This is much easier and less error prone than the low-level method you posted. ALso, QDataStream will take care of host and network byte orders automatically.